# Test case fails but works in WCF Test Client

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, wcf

I have a WCF service and I have written some basic test cases. They call to a database and returns some values. Here is one:

```
public void TestGetDevicesByToteNumber()
    {
        IService1 service = new Service1();
        List<Device> devices = service.GetDevicesByToteNumber(5467);
        Assert.IsTrue(devices.Count > 0);
        foreach (Device device in devices)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(device.ToteNumber == 5467);
        }
    }
```

The implementation is:

```
private ZebraServiceApplication.DAL.DHLScannerContext db = new ZebraServiceApplication.DAL.DHLScannerContext();

public List<Device> GetDevicesByToteNumber(int toteNumber)
    {
        List<Device> devices = db.Devices.Where(x => x.ToteNumber == toteNumber).ToList();
        return devices;
    }
```

Using WCF Test Client everything works fine and I get back the expected list of devices. 
When I run the test from Test Explorer I get no devices.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have encountered this problem. the reason caused this problem due to the difference between the account performing connecting database and the account running the application. please ensure that the application identity has the privilege/permission to connect the database.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I did not have a connection string to the correct database in my test class and EntityFramework supplies a default one which is the one that was being used.